# Printing a list of available bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to make my app print a list of available Bluetooth-enabled devices upon opening the activity.

First I enable Bluetooth on the device:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView3;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        textView3.append("\nBluetooth not supported. Aborting.");
    }
}
```

then I attempt to add any found devices to the Adapter

```
private final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            //add device to the adapter
            btAdapter.add(device.getName(), device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

I know there should be a startDiscovery() call somewhere, but I'm having trouble making sense of other answers online. Also, my btAdapter.add() isn't recognized for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> my btAdapter.add() isn't recognized for some reason.

Because there is no such method in BluetoothAdapter.

> I know there should be a startDiscovery() call somewhere, but I'm having trouble making sense of other answers online.

you can call startDiscovery, once you determine that device supports Bluetooth and Bluetooth is ON from DeviceSettings.